# Java SSL Sockets Client Authentication

Tags: java, sockets, authentication, ssl, client

I have a simple server program collecting data from numerous hardware devices on an open wireless network. I want to make sure that whoever connects to my port can't send commands or listen to my traffic so I need the server to validate the client. I have found a few examples but most seem to take the approach of validating the server from the client side. I'm new to SSL and Socket programming.

From the client I have

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(new FileInputStream("KeyStore"), "password".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(keystore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

context.init(null, trustManagers, null);

SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
return (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(host, port);
```

And on the server I have

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(newFileInputStream("server"),"password".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
server = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(this.port);
```

I'm not exactly sure what everything is doing, but from the example I found it's 2-way authentication, so some overkill. I think I need just one of these pieces of code but don't understand SSL well enough to know which. Which side needs the keystore? Who needs keys and certs? Thanks

Comment: 2-way authentication isn't 'overkill', it is server authentication plus client authentication, which is what you need if you don't want others listening to your traffic. If the server needs to trust the devices, the devices also need to trust the server surely?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing I am most concerned about is someone connecting to my port and attempting to send commands to the server. I am not that concerned about the server authentication because these devices will hold connections to the server for long periods of time. I figured I would reduce the upkeep and complexity by keeping it one-way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to add client authentication to your existing server authentication, add this line at the end of your server code:

```
server.setNeedClientAuth(true);
```

If you only want the server to authorize the client and not vice versa, call `server.setUseClientMode(true)` in the server, and `setUseClientMode(false)` on the SSLSocket you create on the client before returning it.  Note that this option means that the client devices might be connecting to someone else's server, and would have no way of knowing about it.

In either case, the server will need a trust store - which can be the same as its keystore - with a copy of the certificate(s) the clients are presenting installed.  The clients will need key pairs that present this certificate(s).

Comment: Not sure you need to mention `server.setUseClientMode(true)`, it just makes this answer more complicated than it needs to be. This also makes the TCP server the SSL/TLS client and vice versa, so it's no longer really client-certificate authentication.

Comment: That part was included because the asker seemed to want client authentication only - where "client" means "TCP client", not "SSL/TLS client".  I agree it's not the normal use case, but I wanted to answer the question fully.